# Should "character-explanation" and "character-analysis" tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[One](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/60) of the two questions with the tag "character-explanation" can be interpreted as a character analysis and also the term used in literature is generally "character analysis". Should these tags be synonyms?

Comment: You can decide if these tags should be merged, but tag synonym aren't really appropriate here. Synonyms were intended to link two completely different words meaning essentially the same thing (think 'car' vs 'auto'). There's no need to bulk up the tag listings where text completion will help guide the user to the correct usage: `c` `h` `a` `r` > `character-analysis`

Comment: I think I may have created one of them, and if so, am completely onboard with merging either way. I think "analysis" is slightly better, sounds more professional.

Comment: For that matter, do we need either of these tags at all?

Answer (score 1):

Merging the tags would be much more appropriate than making them synonyms.  As already mentioned in comments, this isn't what synonyms are for.

Merging tags is a moderator function, wait until we get them and then issue a gentle reminder.

Comment: Regarding the merge, that can for few tags essentially be done by everyone with edit privileges.